# Filtering with checkboxes with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, state, use-state

I have an array of things

```
const reportsData = [
    {
      name: 'Walter',
      Laudos: 1,
    },
    {
      name: 'John',
      Laudos: 20,
    },
  ]
```

Then on my react component, i need that when i click a checkbox, it sets a state that maked my list filter only that name. Like:

const [searchUser, setSearchUser] = useState('')

```
{reportsData
                .filter((value: any) => {
                  if (searchUser == '') {
                    return value
                  } else if (
                    value.name
                      .toLowerCase()
                      .includes(searchUser.toLowerCase())
                  ) {
                    return value
                  }
                })
```

then on the checkbox

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  checked={john} // just for example
  onChange={john} // just for example
  className="focus:ring-indigo-500 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded"
/>
```

I need that when i press this one, it changes the `searchUser` value to 'John'.

Looked many responses in here but every one of them was messy asf or used `this.setState` instead of the useState.

How could i achieve this?

Comment: if you mean that when the user press the button you want to add 'john' text to the search state, use this in the button `onChange={() => { setSearchUser('john') } }`

Comment: Is not a button, is an input with the type `checkbox`. And just adding this doesn't work cause, when i press the checkbox, yes it works, but when i check it back off, the filter on the array won't return to the default value.

I need that, when i check the checkbox off, the `setSearchUse` returns to `(' ')`

Comment: sorry, I didn't know you want to change it back to the original state, I am providing an answer now in the answers section

Answer (score 0):

define the state this way:

```js
const [searchUser, setSearchUser] = useState([])
```

then add each checkbox this way:

```js
<input
  type="checkbox"
  thisUser="john" // just change this name to make checkbox for another user
  defaultChecked={false}
  onChange={changeSearchUser}
  className="focus:ring-indigo-500 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded"
/>
```

add this function to your component:

```js
function changeSearchUser(e){
  if (e.target.checked) {
    setSearchUser(previousSreach => [...previousSreach, e.target.thisUser])
  }
  else {
    setSearchUser(previousSreach => {
      const index = previousSreach.indexOf(e.target.thisUser)
      if (index > -1) {
        return previousSreach.splice(index, 1);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, it works. But is not quite as i expected. Cause it only works when i select one checkbox, and i need it to work with multiple ones.
Like, i have 10 users, and i need to be able to check 2, 3, 4 checkboxes and it filters them all checked.

Comment: do you want to sperate them using maybe something like `'john,alex,test'` or make an array of checked checkboxes like `['john', 'alex', 'test']`

Comment: i don't get how i could apply this one. Could you show on the code?

For the filter itself and on the checkboxes `onChange`?

Comment: sure, i will update the answer

Comment: didn't work. Says it can't find 'array'. I tried changing to Array, but then i got: `TypeError: Array.indexOf is not a function`

Comment: @HenriqueMonteiro i have updated the line with the error